# How to use a bluetooth speaker?

Tags: debian, audio, pulseaudio, bluetooth, bluez

I'm trying to use a bluetooth speaker, but don't get any sound.

`bluetoothctl` shows the device as paired, trusted, and connected, and lists it as "serial port", "headset", "audio sink", and some others.

`pavucontrol` shows the speaker as "Output Device". But `xfce4-mixer`, while showing the speaker in the "Sound card" dropdown, does not allow me to actually select the device. Also, I wonder what device string I have to put into my `.quodlibet/config` to use the speaker (gst_pipeline = pulsesink device=???).

OS is Debian (stretch/testing).

Answer (score 1):

This quodlibet config entry works:

```
gst_pipeline = pulsesink device=bluez_sink.AB_AB_AB_AB_AB_AB
```

Still no way to use the xfce4 mixer nor the volume keys of the laptop.